# Accepting a job offer from a competitor without burning bridges

Tags: quitting, resignation, competition

Before I describe my situation, I'm fully aware of many such questions that are similar but I would like to ask for some specific advice. First, I'm working for an Enterprise Software company and I got a job offer from another company who are not our direct competitor but in some ways we do see them doing part of what we do. They are also small compared to my current employer. My main reason to leave is that I will get around 70% raise.

I have checked my offer, handbook and there is no non-compete document that I signed. I will never divulge any confidential information as well as I do like my current employer except for the insulting pay.

Just like any other US company, this is also at will and with a 2 week notice. If I tell them that I'm quitting to work for the competitor I'm sure they will let me go immediately mainly due to the fact that we see them as one of our indirect competitor.

How can I leave in the most professional manner and also will this impact me in the future if someone asks for a reference?

Comment: tbh I;m not really seeing anything here that requires *specific advice* over and above the other questions of it's like.  Could you elaborate on specifically how this situation is unique, and how those other questions fail to answer it?

Comment: This question is overly broad.  I'm not going to VTC, but you need to tighten it up to a specific, addressable question.

Comment: You can close this question. I think you guys are right. I was just looking for someone to answer mine as I was thinking about it quite a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was in similar shoes many years ago.

I'd just received an offer from another company, and I was thinking about it, when my boss asked me to tackle something.  I told him the truth, that I'd gotten an offer somewhere else, and was thinking it over, and didn't feel good about starting something I might not be able to finish.

He asked me if I was willing to say how much the offer was.  I told him the number.  He said, and I quote, "John, you'd be a fool not to take that!"

A 70% raise is in that category.

You are under no obligation to tell them who the new employer is.  Just tell them you've received an offer somewhere else, and it is too good to pass up.

Comment: Just tell them ... after you signed the contract.

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf sorry... The advice here on SE is to never take a counter offer.  The premise of the 'raise' is you are thinking of leaving.  They'll most certainly be preparing for that in the long term.

Comment: Oh, comment deleted.